# Why does DB2 put my UserId from the connection string as my table name?

Tags: entity-framework-core, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to us Entity Framework Core to query my DB2 database. Here's how I register it:

```
services.AddDbContext<DB2Contexte>(options =>
                options.UseDb2(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB2"),
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.SetServerInfo(IBMDBServerType.AS400, IBMDBServerVersion.AS400_07_01);
                        builder.UseRowNumberForPaging();
                        builder.MaxBatchSize(1);
                    }));
```

That's the class the is use as a DbSet:

[image]

And there's my connection string:

Server=something;UserID=U_SERVTI;Password=something;Database=something; LibraryList=something;CurrentFunctionPath=*LIBL

Than when I try to query the database using simple LINQ:

```
_dbContext.PersonneRessource.FirstOrDefault()
```

I get this error:

ERROR [42704] [IBM][AS] SQL0204N  "U_SERVTI.DX37PERE" is an undefined name.

Why is the UserId in the name? Shouldn't it just query the table and leave out the UserID?

I use IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-lnx version 3.1.0.500.

Comment: Try `[Table("DX37PERE", Schema="dbo")]` or other appropriate Schema name.

Comment: This is the documented and expected behaviour, for all Db2 platforms including i-series. When you want to address a different schema  (other than the default authid = connecting userid) then you can adjust either the `CURRENT SCHEMA` special register dynamically, or via a connection string argument, or adjust the query to qualify the name. Refer to the Db2 for I documentation for details.

Comment: I don't want any schema. When I do the queries by hand, I do ```Select something From DX37PERE``` and it works. I have no use to put a Schema. How can I achieve that using EF Core with DB2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Db2 for IBM i, for historical reasons, supports two naming conventions; SYS and SQL.

By default, external connections will use SQL naming and like the rest of the Db2 family, unqualified table references will be implicitly qualified with the "run-time authorization identifier"; normally the user id used to connect.

With SYS naming, unqualified table references are qualified with *LIBL and the library list is used to find the table.

On your connection string, you're going to want to add `Naming=SYS`  (or maybe `Naming=*SYS` )

Note that SYS vs. SQL naming affects just about every unqualified reference.  Be sure to look at the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=conventions-qualification-unqualified-object-names).

Comment: Naming is not a valid argument in the connection string. What should my connection string should look like or where do I need to add this Naming attribute?

Comment: what Db2 driver are you using?

Comment: I don't know if I'm being honest. But the documentation I'm following is https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=properties-connectionstring and you can see that there's no Naming attribute in the list of Additional Keywords. With your answer, I tried to add CurrentSchema in my connection string and it worked. However, is there a way to not specify the schema, but make it look into the list in the LibraryList? And still better, is there a way to do all that without even changing the connection string?

Comment: if you're actually using Db2 Connect driver, it's [SystemNaming](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=properties-systemnaming)